# Credit freeze in UK

Tags: united-kingdom, credit-score, credit-history, identity-theft

I've read a lot that in US people can protect themselves from identity theft by applying credit freeze on their credit history, is there similar option in UK?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Yes](http://www.thisismoney.co.uk/money/cardsloans/article-1615240/Freeze-your-credit-history-under-new-law.html) there is. It seems to be very similar to how it is done in the US.

> There are several ways that bank customers in the UK can currently
>   freeze their credit files, but it can be cumbersome to unfreeze should
>   you suddenly need access to more credit.
>
> One is to place a security
>   note on your credit file with each of the three main UK credit rating
>   agencies – Experian, Equifax or Callcredit – so that lenders know to
>   check with you before authorising a new loan or account.

Answer (score 3):

[cifas](http://www.cifas.org.uk) is what you are looking for. You can opt for [Protective Registration](https://www.cifas.org.uk/services/identity-protection/protective-registration)
which make banks or lending agencies to ask for additional identity proofs when opening a new account. This will be updated to all credit agencies (Experian, Equifax  etc.) within weeks and you can see this in your credit report. When I had an incident that might compromise my identity, I opted for this service and called all my banks to cancel my existing cards and asked for a replacement and all my banks sent me new cards within a week (for free) voiding all my previous cards, rendering them useless.